# "Near initialization for..." in array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I always did the following and I don't why but it started giving me the warning.

I'm doing:

```
float (*normalyze_type[5])(void) = {trap, trap, trap, filter, trap};
```

at the top of the .c file in order for that to be a global array of pointers.

For some reason gcc is giving me the following warnings:

```
 (near initialization for ‘normalize_type[0]’) [enabled by default] normalize.c ... line 13 C/C++ Problem
 (near initialization for ‘normalize_type[1]’) [enabled by default] normalize.c ... line 13 C/C++ Problem
 (near initialization for ‘normalize_type[2]’) [enabled by default] normalize.c ... line 13 C/C++ Problem
 (near initialization for ‘normalize_type[3]’) [enabled by default] normalize.c ... line 13 C/C++ Problem
 (near initialization for ‘normalize_type[4]’) [enabled by default] normalize.c ... line 13 C/C++ Problem
```

Already searched the internet and did not found and appropriate solution.
Anyone knows how I can solve this?

Edit:

**Code for the trap():**

```
float trap( const Membership *mf, float x )
{
# define p(pIdx)        mf->parameters[ pIdx ]

if( x < p(B) )  
    return ( x - p(A) ) / ( p(B) - p(A) );

if( x > p(C) )      
    return ( p(D) - x ) / ( p(D) - p(C) );

return 1.0

#undef p
}
```

**Code for filter():**

```
float filter( const Membership *mf, float x )
{
if( x >= mf->parameters[threshold] )
    return x;

return 0.0;
 }
```

Comment: You should post a complete warning message, as well as the declarations of `trap` and `filter`.

Comment: The warning message is complete. The ... is just the name of the project. But yes, I'm going to post the code to `trap` and `filter`, thank you for the advice

Comment: Side note -- why are you attempting to return a `floating point` value from your functions declared as type `int`?

Comment: Corrected. Was just a typo, they all return floats

Comment: trap and filter are not `int (*)(void)`. I believe this is UB.

Comment: You have to have a function declaration for trap and for filter BEFORE the line that initializes the array.

Comment: Two spellings for `normal*ze_type`?

Comment: You did not post the complete compiler output. The "(near" message appears after an error (or warning) to advise where the error occurred. Also, gcc does not output "C/C++ Problem"  . It seems like you are running the compiler output through some sort of filter that is mangling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of the initializer for variable `normalyze_type` do not have the correct type.  They should have type `float (*)(void)`, but they *actually* all have type `float (*)(const Membership *, float)`.

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thank you very much for the help.